# CRUD operation for .net-core web API with interfaces - saveChanges() doesn't exist

Tags: c#, sql-server, api, asp.net-core-mvc, crud

### Overview

I am making a .net-core web API with simple CRUD operations.

I have made the GET methods and got them up and running, however when I try to implement the Create method using dbContext.Add(myItem) I am not able to use dbContext.SaveChanges() afterwards.

My current work is available at:
https://github.com/petermefrandsen/TKD-theory-API

### So far

I have tried adding a overwriting method to my database context.
Additionally I have tried adding the entity framework reference to the project.

As I do use interfaces for loose coupling I am at a loss when I comes to comparing with tutorials and other peoples similar problems. (read I am fairly new to c#).

### Code

Controller:

```
[Route("dan/")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<DanTheoryItem> PostDanTheoryItem(DanTheoryItem danTheoryItem)
{
    _context.PostDanTheoryItem(danTheoryItem);
    return new ActionResult<DanTheoryItem>(danTheoryItem);
}
```

IContext:

```
DanTheoryItem PostDanTheoryItem(DanTheoryItem danTheoryItem);
```

Context:

```
public DanTheoryItem PostDanTheoryItem(DanTheoryItem danTheoryItem)
{
    var theoryItem = new DbDanTheoryItems
    {
        Id = danTheoryItem.Id,
        KoreanTheoryItemId = danTheoryItem.KoreanTheoryItemId,
        MainCategory = danTheoryItem.MainCategory,
        SubCategory = danTheoryItem.SubCategory,
        SubToSubCategory = danTheoryItem.SubToSubCategory,
        NameLatin = danTheoryItem.NameLatin,
        NamePhonetic = danTheoryItem.NamePhonetic,
        NameAudio = danTheoryItem.NameAudio
    };
    _dbContext.DanTheoryItems.Add(theoryItem);
    //_dbContext.SaveChanges();
    return danTheoryItem;
}
```

### Desired result

I'd like to have the controller call the context methods that will write the desired data to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interface doesn't contain a SaveChanges method. Since you are using dependency injection only the methods in your interface will be available to your controller.
If you inherit from System.Data.Entity.IDbContext class in your custom interface, the method will be exposed to you in your controller.

Instantiating an instance of your DbLokisaurTKDTheoryAppContext class in your controller will expose the SaveChanges method as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer it was really helpful for me getting further with the post request!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say exactly because you've neglected to post certain key portions of your code. However, my best guess is that you "context" is being provided `IDbContext` (of your own creating), instead of `DbContext`, and your interface doesn't define a `SaveChanges` method.

Honestly, just get rid of `IDbContext`. The point of an interface is to define a contract between multiple implementations. Here, there can be only one implementation: `DbContext`, and `DbContext` isn't even aware of this interface. Just inject your derived `DbContext` directly.

Using an interface isn't a magic wand. You have a hard dependency on Entity Framework here, so interface or not, you're tightly coupled. That's not necessary a *bad* thing though. EF is serving as your data layer, and this application is data driven; it's going to be tightly coupled to the data layer no matter what.

The API itself serves as your abstraction. Other layers will presumably just use the API, so no further abstraction is necessary, and in fact just adds more maintenance concern with no added benefit.

Comment: I agree. I would however in addition to this recommend using the repository pattern for easier testing

Comment: No, no, no, a million times no. The repository pattern is wrong here, because EF is an ORM that *already* implements this pattern. Also, EF is already testable; a repository layer is not necessary for testing.

Comment: I doesn't think that the answer to that is as clear-cut as you state since the pattern has several advantages. Nevertheless it is true that you could utilize the in-memory database for testing

Comment: No, it's very clear-cut. The repository pattern has one purpose: abstracting away *low-level* database querying logic. That is already done by ORMs like Entity Framework. There could be arguments made for using a *different* pattern such as CQRS, microservices, etc. that provide additional benefits, but not for the repository pattern.

Comment: Thank you for the insight in both my question and my use of interface - I now got it up and running and gained further insight in structuring my API code.